# Closure of $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> **Exercise**: What is the closure in $\mathbb{R}$of each of the following set:
>
> i) $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}$

My attempt: I consider the topological space $\mathbb{R},\tau$, where $\tau$ is the following topology $\tau=\mathbb{R}\cup\emptyset\cup\{(a,b):\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$

The open sets can be defined as $\{A\in\tau:\text{such that} \forall a \in A\:\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}, a\in(x,y)\subseteq A\}$

$\forall i\in \mathbb{N},\frac{1}{i}\in\mathbb{R}$

For elements $\frac{1}{i_1}$ and  $\frac{1}{i_1}$ there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{i_1}\in(x,y)$ but $\frac{1}{i_1}\notin(x,y)$

Then $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}$ has not limit points then $\overline{\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}}=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}$

**Question:**

I am not really sure about the step "*there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{i_1}\in(x,y)$ but $\frac{1}{i_1}\notin(x,y)$"*

Is my proof right? If not is there any way to prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your definition of $\tau$ doesn't make sense: you are using $\tau$ to define it!

Comment: “There exists $x, y$ such that some property holds, but also does not hold?”

Comment: each point of your set if isolated, so you get the set itself, and the only limiting point which is $0$.

Comment: @Hayk I can find an open interval that contains 0 but not 1.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the insight. Please check my update.

Comment: @PedroGomes, "I can find an open interval that contains 0 but not 1" is not relevant to $0$ being a limiting point. You need to to show that any (small) neighborhood of $0$ contains a point from your set other than $0$. This is obviously true, making $0$ into the closure.

Comment: @Hayk           Of course! I am sorry. I forgot that $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroGomes Your new $\tau$ isn't a topology, since $(-1,0),(0,1)\in\tau$, but $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\notin\tau$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you help me define the topology?

Comment: Any topology containing the open intervals should generate the usual metric topology, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг That is right,

Comment: Then the closure has the usual definition of set plus limit points. Now, you have to find the limit points in the standard topology.

Comment: Why don't you just say that you are working with the usual topology? It least, I think that that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your definition of $\tau$ is standart topology on $\mathbb{R}$. And you may say the base of it must be $\{(a,b):\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. And now say any $a\in \mathbb{R^+}$. By using precible of Archimedes, you can find $m>0$ integer such that $\frac{1}{m}<a$. So $\frac{1}{m}\in{\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}} $ and $\frac{1}{m}\in (-a,a)$. Since $(-a,a)$ is an arbitrary neighbourhood of $0$  then $0\in\overline{\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}}\neq\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\frac{1}{n},...\}$